# Vue 3 defineAsyncComponent does not trigger onUpdated when mounting is done

Tags: vuejs3, async-components

In my Vue 3 application with Vite and Pinia I have a component that imports multiple accordion subcomponents. When all accordions are mounted, I get the list with querySelectorAll.

```
const Byg = defineAsyncComponent(() => import('@/components/bbrObject/entityType/Byg.vue')); // Includes a lot of .accordion-button elements

const accordionList = ref([]);

onUpdated(() => {
  accordionList.value = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.accordion-button')) as HTMLElement[];
  console.log(accordionList.value); // <-- Empty with async import
});
```

This works like a charm when I import my subcomponents directly, but as soon as I update my accordion subcomponents to be imported using defineAsyncComponent, onUpdated is still triggered but the accordionList remains empty.

My issue is that I can't find a way to know when my async components are done rendering, so I can access the DOM. I have tried adding watchers, used nextTick and even tried with a setTimeout. I also tried using the promise returned by defineAsyncComponent. I can't figure out a clean way to know when all async components are done loading.

I have set up an example of the issue: https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-morning-frqtlv?file=/src/App.vue

Comment: Please post a code snippet instead of a code image. It is better for someone who searches the similar question and for folks who want to test your code. Btw, you should show your template structure, where you use the async components.

Comment: I have added a sandbox link that shows the issue. Thx

Comment: The codesandbox is good for reproducing problems but you still should include your code snippet in your question (like my answer below) Because every external link can be unavailable one day

Comment: I have added a code snippet

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to detect when the async component is mounted is by explicitly [emitting](https://vuejs.org/api/options-state.html#emits) an event from it.

```html
<!-- HelloWorld.vue -->
<script setup>
const emit = defineEmits<{
  (e: 'mounted'): void
}>()
onMounted(()=>{
  emit('mounted')
})
</script>
```

Then you can listen to the mounted event on your parent component

```html
<!-- App.vue -->
<template>
  <HelloWorld @mounted="onAsyncMounted" msg="Hello Vue 3 in CodeSandbox!" />
</template>

<script setup>
const HelloWorld = defineAsyncComponent(() =>
  import("./components/HelloWorld.vue")
);

function onAsyncMounted() {
  // Now you can access DOM of the async component
}
</script>
```

Suspense provides a [resolve event](https://vuejs.org/guide/built-ins/suspense.html#events). But since it is still an experimental feature, I do not recommend using it.

Comment: I thought about this, I just hoped that there was a cleaner way to register it from the parent component. I have 20 components that are imported async so it is not the prettiest way to emit mounted events from all of them. But I guess that's the only way to go. Thx

Comment: @CasperSlynge You can create a composable and use it in all your child components. Or you can just adopt suspense. It is an experimental feature but yeah, I see many developers used it

Comment: Thx. Using a composable is not a bad idea.